# What is the difference between case, case+ and case- in ATS?

Tags: ats

I often see a case-expression in ATS formed using `case`, `case+`, or `case-`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Using `case` will issue a warning if the expression is not exhaustive, `case+` will yield an error instead, while `case-` will suppress the message about exhaustiveness altogether. See [this chapter](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/x1031.html) of INT2PROGINATS for further detail.